# Linq contains of an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of values and trying to filter my linq query to see if any majorchains contain any of the values from the array. Majorchains is a string delimited string.

**Filter by**

```
var array = new string[]{"Checkers", "Usave"};
```

**Query**

```
var query = _dbContext.Promotions.Where(e => array.Contains(e.MajorChain));
```

Example of how Majorchains is stored: "Checkers, OK Franchise, Shop Check Butchery, Shoprite, Usave"
[image]

What is currently happening, if there is just 1 item in there array filter it returns all data fine. Once there is more than 1 it returns an empty list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "normalize" is a question of definition. Storing it in comma-separated form can be optimal in some cases.

Comment: What LINQ are you using? LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? What database provider?

Comment: BTW, in C# type is all important. What is the type of `array`? What is the type of `e.MajorChain`? Then what overload of `Contains` is called, and what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), or a dedicated simplified internal version, you can create a method to expand the filter expression to something that can be translated to SQL.

```
// string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value delimited string field to test
// delimiter - string separator between values in test field
// value - string value to find in splits of test field
// r => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SplitContains<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, string value) {
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r) == value);
    pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).StartsWith(value + delimiter));
    pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).EndsWith(delimiter + value));
    pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).Contains(delimiter + value + delimiter));

    return pred;
}

// values - string values, one of which to find in splits of test field
// string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value delimited string field to test
// delimiter - string separator between values in test field
// r => values.Any(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value))
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AnySplitContains<T>(this IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter) {
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
    foreach (var value in values)
        pred = pred.Or(fieldExpr.SplitContains(delimiter, value));

    return pred;
}
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SplitContainsAny<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, IEnumerable<string> values) =>
    values.AnySplitContains(fieldExpr, delimiter);
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SplitContainsAny<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, params string[] values) =>
    values.AnySplitContains(fieldExpr, delimiter);

// values - string values, one of which to find in splits of test field
// string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value delimited string field to test
// delimiter - string separator between values in test field
// dbq.Where(r => values.Any(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)))
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnySplitContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter) =>
    dbq.AsExpandable().Where(values.AnySplitContains(fieldExpr, delimiter));
public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContainsAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, IEnumerable<string> values) =>
    dbq.AsExpandable().Where(values.AnySplitContains(fieldExpr, delimiter));
public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContainsAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, params string[] values) =>
    dbq.AsExpandable().Where(values.AnySplitContains(fieldExpr, delimiter));
```

Basically, every value is tested for belonging in the database field by testing for being exactly equal to the value, starting with the value+delimiter, ending with delimiter+value, or containing delimiter+value+delimiter. Each of these tests translate to SQL using `LIKE`.

Using this method, you can write your query:

```
var query = _dbContext.Promotions.WhereAnySplitContains(array, e => e.MajorChain, ", ");
```

NOTE: The delimiter is assumed to be consistent - you must have either "," or ", " between every value in the field.

Answer (score 0):

That's because irrespective of the number of words you have for any MajorColumn, it would all still be treated as a string. You could split each MajorChain column value by the comma separating the words into an array of strings.

```
var query = _dbContext.Promotions.Where(e =>
  e.MajorChain.Split(',').Any(a=>Array.Contains(a)));
```

Comment: @Charlieface To be honest, I've stared at this for some minutes and I can't see how best I can split it beforehand while still returning those rows that contain items in the array

Comment: Sorry misread thought it was an outside variable being split. By the way, you can shorten to a direct delegate `.Any(array.Contains)` although that can be confusing for some

Comment: @Charlieface Wawu, this weird ): technique will take some time getting used to for me.